# Is $12$ the only number that has the same digits as its prime factorization?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Let us represent a number $x$ as a string of "digits" where each $n^{th}$ digit represents the power that you raise the $n^{th}$ prime to in its prime factorization

For example, $15=5^13^12^0$ so we would write $15=110$. In the event that a prime power is larger than $9$, we would just specify that the specific digit is larger. For example

$$
885735=5^13^{11}2^0\rightarrow 1(11)0
$$

Now we can see that $12=3^12^2$ so we would write $12=12$.

Is it the case that $12$ is the only number that is the same in both of these representations? I wrote some code to check the first $10^6$ cases and found that we only have $12$.

Clearly we cannot have $x$ be an odd number if we want the representations to be the same, but outside of simple cases like this I cannot think of a way to trim the cases

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146050/discussion-on-question-by-wjmccann-is-12-the-only-number-that-has-the-same-dig); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but too long to fit in a comment. This shows that if $k\geq100$, then $k$ must be divisible by the cube of a prime. There is plenty of room for improvement of the argument, to restrict the factorization of $k$ further.

---

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime number, with $p_1=2$. For any positive integer $k$ with prime factorization $k=\prod p_n^{e_n}$, define
$$f(k):=\sum e_n10^n.$$
Let $k$ be a positive integer such that $e_n\leq9$ for all $n$, and $f(k)=k$. If $k$ is odd then $e_1=0$ and so $f(k)$ is a multiple of $10$, contradicting the fact that $f(k)=k$ is odd. Then $k$ is even and so $e_1>0$. Then $e_1\in\{2,4,6,8\}$ and the final digit of $k$ is not $0$, so $k$ is not divisible by $5$ and so $e_3=0$. Moreover, if $e_1\in\{2,6\}$ then $e_2$ is odd, otherwise $e_2$ is even.

The largest prime divisor of $k$ is $p_m$ where $m=\lceil\log_{10}k\rceil$, and so
$$k=\prod_{n=1}^mp_n^{e_n}\leq\prod_{n=1}^mp_n^9=(p_m\#)^9,$$
where $p_m\#$ denotes the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) function, which is by definition the product of the first $m$ prime numbers. If $m\geq3$ we can improve this slightly by using the fact that $k$ is not divisible by $5$, to find
$$k\leq\frac{1}{5^9}(p_m\#)^9.$$

In fact if $e$ is the largest exponent of a prime power in the factorization of $k$, we find in the same way that
$$k\leq\frac{1}{5^e}(p_m\#)^e,$$
where still $m=\lceil\log_{10}k\rceil$. Then $m<1+\log_{10}k$, and from the upper bound $p_m\#\leq2.763^m$ (see the wikipedia page) it follows that
$$k\leq\frac{1}{5^e}(p_m\#)^e<2.763^{e(1+\log_{10}k)}=\left(\frac{2.763}{5}\right)^e\cdot k^{e\log_{10}2.763}.$$
This shows that $e\log_{10}2.763>1$ and hence that $e\geq3$. That is to say $k$ is divisibile by the cube of a prime.

Comment: Of course much more is true; as $m$ increases, an ever larger proportion of primes must have a large exponent. I do not have time to get into the gritty details of this, however, and welcome anyone else to try to quantify this.